# How can I maintain the same pandas DataFrame after using sklearn imputer?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I am trying to replace all my NaN values by using Imputer. However, sklearn imputer changes my data into a numpy array. How can I make it replace all the NaN values while not changing my data into a numpy array?

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('my_data')

imp = Imputer(strategy='median')
imp.fit(df)
df = imp.transform(df)
```

When I check my data after I do that, I don't get the nicely formatted data I had before, but rather a numpy array.

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace the values in the original `DataFrame` from the new numpy array. You can do:

1. Iterate over the columns in the dataframe and assign numpy columns to it:

   ```
   for i, col in enumerate(df.columns):
       df[col] = df2[:,i]
   ```
2. Directly assign all the columns:

   ```
   df[df.columns] = df2
   ```
3. Create a new `DataFrame` with the numpy array using the column and index from older one:

   ```
   df_new = pd.DataFrame(df2, columns = df.columns, index=df.index)
   ```
4. If using `Imputer` is not a compulsion, then directly use the [`pandas.fillna()` method](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html#pandas.DataFrame.fillna):

   ```
   df = df.fillna(df.median())
   ```

Answer (score -1):

One easy way ->

```
df = pd.read_csv('my_data')
col = ['a','b','c','d']  #save your columns in an array
imp = Imputer(strategy='median')
imp.fit(df)
df = imp.transform(df)
df = pd.Dataframe(df,columns=col) # COnvert it back to dataframe.
```

This will convert the array to Pandas dataframe.